# What is the Date format

Tags: ios, objective-c

What is the date and time format for "06/08/2016 09:50:12" to be converted to "dd MMMM YYYY HH:mm"?, which i'm converting the NSDate to NSString.

Comment: Have you read any documentation?

Comment: Use format : dd/MMMM/yyyy HH:MM"

Comment: [Date Format Patterns](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Comment: Have you try my answer.

Comment: My answer is correct, check my answer?

Comment: Is the date string in 12 or 24 hour format? That's important. @IyyappanRavi your answer is not correct if the date string is in 24 hour format.

Comment: in here the Capital H will give you the 24 hours time format and lowerCase "h" will give you the 12 hours time format...my answer mensioned 12 hours format

Comment: @megha is your time is 12 hour or 24 hours format?

Comment: my format is24hours format

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this,

```
    NSString *strDate = @"06/08/2016 09:50:12";
    NSDateFormatter *format= [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [format setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:s"];
    NSDate *date = [format dateFromString:strDate];
    NSLog(@"%@",date);
```

To convert this date into string :

```
    NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [format setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:s"];
    NSString *str = [format stringFromDate:date];
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 2):

Use this code,

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *result = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
```

its working for me, hope its helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
NSDateFormatter *format= [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];

// string to date
NSString *dateStr = @"06/08/2016 01:50:12";
NSDate *date = [format dateFromString:dateStr];

// date to string
[format setDateFormat:@"dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm"];
NSString *dateStr2 = [format stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@", dateStr2);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
NSDateFormatter *format= [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"];

// string to date
NSString *dateStr = @"06/08/2016 01:50:12";
NSDate *date = [format dateFromString:dateStr];
NSLog(@"%@", date);

// date to string
NSDate *date2 = [NSDate date];
NSString *dateStr2 = [format stringFromDate:date2];
NSLog(@"%@", dateStr2);

//@"dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"
//dd is for the day.
//MM is for the month.
//YYYY is for the year.
//HH is for the hour.
//mm is for the minute.
//ss is for the second.
```